# Compute mean difference between dates based on a condition in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have this dataset:

```
Date New_Renew
 2019-01-10 22:11:16  Renewing
 2019-02-23 00:21:48  Renewing
 2019-03-05 05:26:17  Renewing
 2019-04-18 15:05:10       NEW
 2019-04-18 15:07:52       NEW
 2019-04-26 11:32:25  Renewing
 2019-05-03 14:15:25  Renewing
 2019-05-08 21:10:08       NEW
 2019-05-16 13:35:57  Renewing
 2019-05-24 13:18:23  Renewing
 2019-06-01 12:42:21  Renewing
 2019-06-17 18:08:09  Renewing
 2019-06-26 13:40:29  Renewing
 2019-12-13 17:57:43  Renewing
 2020-01-03 11:49:14  Renewing
 2020-01-11 11:46:51  Renewing
 2020-01-14 21:08:08       NEW
 2020-01-18 21:14:30       NEW
 2020-01-21 16:08:37       NEW
 2020-01-28 11:41:44  Renewing
 2020-01-30 13:34:21  Renewing
 2020-02-03 13:29:37  Renewing
 2020-02-18 17:15:52  Renewing
 2020-02-20 13:37:52  Renewing
 2020-02-24 12:55:25  Renewing
 2020-02-26 21:13:38       NEW
 2020-03-04 13:23:41  Renewing
 2020-03-09 16:48:36  Renewing
```

What I want is, when the New_Renew variable is equal to NEW, to compute the mean of the difference between the dates associated to NEW. In simple words, how frequently is a user doing a NEW transaction.

Comment: What do you mean "the mean of the difference between the dates associated to NEW"?  There's only one date associated with each instance of NEW, so for the first instance of NEW the difference you'd like is between the (one) associated date and what?

Comment: For example, difference between the first two NEW observations, then the difference between the 2nd and the 3rd NEW observation and so on. Finally, I want the mean of these differences.

Comment: For your "put simply" question: "How frequently is a user doing a NEW transaction?" The answer could also be: "1 in every 4 transactions", since the user made 7 NEW transactions out of 28. Or, if you take into account the _whole_ time period, the user made 7 NEW transactions over a period of 424 days. Which is about 1 NEW transaction every 60 days. This is longer than the mean of 52 days because the periods before the first and after the last new transactions are not counted. Just thinking out loud here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate` and `diff`. The `60*24` converts the yielding seconds to days.

```
aggregate(Date ~ New_Renew, dat, function(x) mean(diff(x))/(60*24))
#  New_Renew         Date
# 1       NEW 52.38292438 
# 2  Renewing  0.01471444
```

Or with `tapply`.

```
with(dat, tapply(Date, New_Renew, function(x) mean(diff(x))/(60*24)))
#         NEW    Renewing 
# 52.38292438  0.01471444
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1547154676, 1550877708, 1551759977, 
1555592710, 1555592872, 1556271145, 1556885725, 1557342608, 1558006557, 
1558696703, 1559385741, 1560787689, 1561549229, 1576256263, 1578048554, 
1578739611, 1579032488, 1579378470, 1579619317, 1580208104, 1580387661, 
1580732977, 1582042552, 1582202272, 1582545325, 1582748018, 1583324621, 
1583768916), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), New_Renew = c("Renewing", 
"Renewing", "Renewing", "NEW", "NEW", "Renewing", "Renewing", 
"NEW", "Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", 
"Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "Renewing", 
"Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "Renewing", "NEW", 
"Renewing", "Renewing")), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(New_Renew=="NEW") %>%
  mutate(Date_next=lead(Date), duration=Date_next-Date) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(duration, na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  mean         
  <drtn>       
1 75421.41 mins # ~ 52 days
```

---

Before overall summary:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  Date                New_Renew Date_next           duration       
  <dttm>              <chr>     <dttm>              <drtn>         
1 2019-04-18 15:05:10 NEW       2019-04-18 15:07:52      2.700 mins
2 2019-04-18 15:07:52 NEW       2019-05-08 21:10:08  29162.267 mins
3 2019-05-08 21:10:08 NEW       2020-01-14 21:08:08 361438.000 mins
4 2020-01-14 21:08:08 NEW       2020-01-18 21:14:30   5766.367 mins
5 2020-01-18 21:14:30 NEW       2020-01-21 16:08:37   4014.117 mins
6 2020-01-21 16:08:37 NEW       2020-02-26 21:13:38  52145.017 mins
7 2020-02-26 21:13:38 NEW       NA                          NA mins
```

Answer (score 1):

Create minimal reproducible example first

```r
DT <- read.table(text = 'Date, New_Renew
 2019-01-10 22:11:16,Renewing
 2019-02-23 00:21:48,Renewing
 2019-03-05 05:26:17,Renewing
 2019-04-18 15:05:10,NEW
 2019-04-18 15:07:52,NEW
 2019-04-26 11:32:25,Renewing
 2019-05-03 14:15:25,Renewing
 2019-05-08 21:10:08,NEW
 2019-05-16 13:35:57,Renewing
 2019-05-24 13:18:23,Renewing
 2019-06-01 12:42:21,Renewing
 2019-06-17 18:08:09,Renewing
 2019-06-26 13:40:29,Renewing
 2019-12-13 17:57:43,Renewing
 2020-01-03 11:49:14,Renewing
 2020-01-11 11:46:51,Renewing
 2020-01-14 21:08:08,NEW
 2020-01-18 21:14:30,NEW
 2020-01-21 16:08:37,NEW
 2020-01-28 11:41:44,Renewing
 2020-01-30 13:34:21,Renewing
 2020-02-03 13:29:37,Renewing
 2020-02-18 17:15:52,Renewing
 2020-02-20 13:37:52,Renewing
 2020-02-24 12:55:25,Renewing
 2020-02-26 21:13:38,NEW
 2020-03-04 13:23:41,Renewing
 2020-03-09 16:48:36,Renewing', 
                 sep = ',', 
                 header = T)
```

Then we'll use xts to make convenient calculations on dates. The for loop is straight forward, stores the first renewal and subtracts the first new from

```r
library(data.table)
library(xts)
library(lubridate)
library(tbl2xts)

df <- xts(DT, order.by = ymd_hms(DT$Date))

new_items <- which(DT$New_Renew=="NEW")

dif <- DT

dif$difference <- NA

renewal <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){

  if (df[i,2]=='Renewing' & renewal == 0){
    renewal <- i
  } else if (df[i,2]=='Renewing' & renewal != 0){
    next
  } else if (df[i, 2]=='NEW' & renewal != 0) {
    dif[i, 'difference'] <- index(df[i, 2]) - index(df[renewal, 2])
    renewal <- i
  } else {
    dif[i, 'difference'] <- index(df[i, 2]) - index(df[renewal, 2])
    renewal <- 0
  }

}

mean_diff <- mean(dif$difference, na.rm = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
DT[, Date := as.POSIXct(Date, format="%Y-%m-%d %T")][
    New_Renew=="NEW", mean(diff(Date))]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Date,New_Renew
2019-01-10 22:11:16,Renewing
2019-02-23 00:21:48,Renewing
2019-03-05 05:26:17,Renewing
2019-04-18 15:05:10,     NEW
2019-04-18 15:07:52,     NEW
2019-04-26 11:32:25,Renewing
2019-05-03 14:15:25,Renewing
2019-05-08 21:10:08,     NEW
2019-05-16 13:35:57,Renewing
2019-05-24 13:18:23,Renewing
2019-06-01 12:42:21,Renewing
2019-06-17 18:08:09,Renewing
2019-06-26 13:40:29,Renewing
2019-12-13 17:57:43,Renewing
2020-01-03 11:49:14,Renewing
2020-01-11 11:46:51,Renewing
2020-01-14 21:08:08,     NEW
2020-01-18 21:14:30,     NEW
2020-01-21 16:08:37,     NEW
2020-01-28 11:41:44,Renewing
2020-01-30 13:34:21,Renewing
2020-02-03 13:29:37,Renewing
2020-02-18 17:15:52,Renewing
2020-02-20 13:37:52,Renewing
2020-02-24 12:55:25,Renewing
2020-02-26 21:13:38,     NEW
2020-03-04 13:23:41,Renewing
2020-03-09 16:48:36,Renewing")
```